# str object has no attribute append

Tags: python, nltk

```
import nltk
file = open('SMSm.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('SMSw.txt', 'w')

for line in file.readlines(): 
   if 'Rs' in line: 
      line.append(file2)
```

I am getting an attribute error in the last line of my code. I basically want all the lines with 'Rs' in it. Some of the lines have Rs5000 and some have format as Rs 5000. I want both the line to be appended in the new file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve here? `line` is a string. Strings don't have an `.append()` method. Are you perhaps trying to *write* that line to the other file? Then you'd use `file2.write(line)`.

Comment: Hint: read the error message and think about what it could mean.

Answer (score 1):

You have your understanding about methods all mixed up.

If you want to write to a file object, then you must use the `file.write()` method; it is a member of the file object. Strings know nothing about files and don't care about files, so strings do not have any methods to do with files.

To add your selected lines to `file2` then, you need to call `file2.write(line)`:

```
for line in file.readlines(): 
   if 'Rs' in line: 
      file2.write(line)
```

You may have gotten confused with *lists*; list objects do have a `list.append()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Strings have no `append()` method, to concatenate strings use the `+` operator

```
"string" + "string"
```